# Android SQLite: entry validating/checking

Tags: android, sqlite, android-2.2-froyo

Hoping someone might be able to shine a little light on this for me to help out. I have a EditText field where a user will input a serial number and or reference number, then hit the load Button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/95iWI.png

I made a method to check and see if that number has already been added to the Database. If it hasn't then i have a Yes/No dialog that pops up asking if they want to add to the database. Then if it is in the DB it will load that number's data into the four TextViews.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHbCQ.png

If they select yes then it runs the new intent, switching to the form screen(haven't yet looked into passing the user input to another class yet). but to get back on to my little issue, when testing this in the emulator everything runs fine. Then when i enter a number that i already entered in it still opens the dialog, (i have it in a if statement).

**Load button code**

```
String s = input.getText().toString();
int l = Integer.parseInt(s);
Db load = new Db(this);
load.open();
y = load.dbCheck(l);
if (y != 0) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        switch (which) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.FORM");
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

            break;
        }
        }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Would you like to add to Database?")
    .setTitle("Not in Database:")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
    .show();
} 
else 
{       
    final Dialog dbentery = new Dialog(this);
    dbentery.setTitle("Entry Exists!");
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("The serial number you have entered is already in database");
    dbentery.setContentView(tv);
    dbentery.show();
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            dbentery.dismiss();
            t.cancel();
        }
    }, 2000);
}       
load.close();
```

Now with the method i created I thought I had it right, but something just isn't working. I have it returning a integer back to the load button code where the if statement uses wither 0 or 1 to validate if it is in the DB and what it should do. I figured since it is running the Dialog that it is returning 0, that it might be with the cursor. I looked at a few other posts on here that were similar but didn't seem to help me and or i wasn't comprehending what was being done. So here's the checking method in my DBHelper class

```
/* this is to check to see if entry is in db or not */
public int dbCheck(int l) throws SQLException {
    String[] cols = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ONE, KEY_TWO, KEY_THREE, KEY_FOUR };
    Cursor c = ourDB.query(KEY_TABLE, cols, KEY_ONE + "=" + l, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c == null) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        return 1;
    }       
}
```

this might be a simple fix, but I'm not seeing it... thanks for any help or insight to what i might be doing wrong

Comment: don't you think,you have interchanged the things in if where you are popping up a dialog? i mean,you should have checked,if(l==0){//number not exists in db}else{//number exists } you did reverse...isnt it?

Comment: ahh i completely forgot about changing that, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: (you should also call `Cursor#close()` before exiting your `#dbCheck(int)` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c == null if the query throws an error, otherwise c != null, but c.getCount == 0

```
public int dbCheck(int l) throws SQLException {
String[] cols = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_ONE, KEY_TWO, KEY_THREE, KEY_FOUR };
Cursor c = ourDB.query(KEY_TABLE, cols, KEY_ONE + "=" + l, null,
        null, null, null);
if (c == null) {
    return 0;
}else {
    return c.getCount() == 0 ? 0:1;

  }
```

}

Comment: Awesome that worked ... thank you guys for your help. I will definitely be using both way to kinda help teach myself more. it has been alot of help.

Answer (score 0):

First, rewrite `dbCheck()` to return boolean, not int. No point in having an int if you only return two values, waste of space.

Second, rewrite your query. There is no point in selecting all those columns if you only filter on one of them, and then throw the result away. Rewrite it into this:

```
String s = String.format("SELECT count(*) FROM %s WHERE %s = %d",
                         KEY_TABLE, KEY_ONE, l);
Cursor c = ourDB.rawQuery(s, null);
c.moveToFirst();

return (c.getInt(0) > 0);   // returns a boolean
```

This will cut down the number of quirks you have in your code, and it will help you debug it easier.

EDIT: corrected `query()` into `rawQuery()`.

Comment: eclipse throws an error on this   Cursor c = ourDB.query(s, null);

Comment: Sorry, it should be `rawQuery()`.

Comment: **Awesome that worked ... thank you guys for your help. I will definitely be using both way to kinda help teach myself more. it has been alot of help.**